# When I specify a sm modal I can still see the lg in the background

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am creating a small modal but when shown the lg modal is visible in the background. Any ideas?
I updated my code as suggested.

[image]

After updated html
[image]

```
      <div class="modal-content modal-sm">
          <div class="modal-header">
              <h3 class="modal-title pull-left"><b>{{title}}</b></h3>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'error':newEmailModalForm.get('email').invalid && newEmailModalForm.get('email').dirty}">
                <label for="rev">Email:</label>
                <em *ngIf="newEmailModalForm.get('email').invalid && newEmailModalForm.get('email').dirty">Not Valid Email</em>
                <em>*</em>
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email"  class="form-control" formControlName="email" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer"> 
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="cancel()">{{closeBtnName}}</button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!newEmailModalForm.valid" >{{saveBtnName}}</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

updated html

```
    <div id="myModal" class="modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title pull-left"><b>{{title}}</b></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'error':newEmailModalForm.get('email').invalid && newEmailModalForm.get('email').dirty}">
                <label for="rev">Email:</label>
                <em *ngIf="newEmailModalForm.get('email').invalid && newEmailModalForm.get('email').dirty">Not Valid Email</em>
                <em>*</em>
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email"  class="form-control" formControlName="email" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer"> 
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="cancel()">{{closeBtnName}}</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!newEmailModalForm.valid" >{{saveBtnName}}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the `modal-sm` class on the `modal-content`. But the whole thing should be wrapped in a div that has the `modal` class with a child having `modal-dialog` and that is where the size would be specified. It would look like something below.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title pull-left"><b>{{title}}</b></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'error':newEmailModalForm.get('email').invalid && newEmailModalForm.get('email').dirty}">
                <label for="rev">Email:</label>
                <em *ngIf="newEmailModalForm.get('email').invalid && newEmailModalForm.get('email').dirty">Not Valid Email</em>
                <em>*</em>
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email"  class="form-control" formControlName="email" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer"> 
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="cancel()">{{closeBtnName}}</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!newEmailModalForm.valid" >{{saveBtnName}}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I change to the code above all I see is the backdrop. I can press the esc key and it fades away but no modal is displayed.

Comment: I was able to test and made some changes to the code. The modal will display correctly now

Comment: I must still be doing something wrong. I updated my post.

Comment: It is going to be hidden to start. Are you invoking it to show? eg.button press or are you just wanting it to show right away?

Comment: A button press.ex `this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(AddEmailComponent, { keyboard: true, backdrop: true, ignoreBackdropClick : true });`

Answer (score 0):

When using a BsModalRef you provide the modal size through the config object. Found the answer [here](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/2385).

```
this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(NewEmailComponent, { class: 'modal-sm'});
```